# Impressionist gem - sort posts by views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, impressionist

I'm using the following [gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#adding-a-counter-cache) and now I'm trying to sort posts by the number of views.

I have followed the instructions and in my post model, so I have:

```
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true
```

And in my controller, I have:

```
@mostpopular = @posts.order('counter_cache DESC').limit(6)
```

But I'm getting an error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: counter_cache: SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY counter_cache DESC LIMIT 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added field to your model?

```
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true
```

> This will automatically increment the impressions_count column in the
>   included model. Note: **You'll need to add that column to your model.**

To add you can do:

```
t.integer :my_column_name, :default => 0
```

[Read about this moment](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#adding-column-to-model)